# Bada: проблемы с кодировкой.

Tags: c++

Как в Bada перевести строку кириллицы такой как, например, "папа" в следующий вид:
"%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0" ?
Все примеры которые рассчитаны на чистый C++ не подходят.

Comment: %D0 - это 16-ричный код байта со знаком процента в начале. Сделайте из строки массив байтов и переводите каждый байт в 16-ричное представление. Дополните представление каждого байта спереди знаком процента - и все :)

Comment: @uilenspiegel, все конечно хорошо, но если я запишу например String str = "папа", то ничего хорошего не выйдет, в нее запишется какая-то фигня

Comment: и как там пишется на баде?))

Comment: @Gorets, Хуже не бывает) даже пробовать не стоит) но меня нужда заставила..

Comment: @Мария_1 Используйте [`wide strings`.](http://developer.bada.com/help_2.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppappprogramming.help/html/dev_guide/base/string.htm) Конкретно в вашем прошлом примере можете использовать `String str(L"папа")`. Далее уже используйте [`UrlEncoder`](http://developer.bada.com/help_2.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.osp.cppappprogramming.help/html/dev_guide/base/url_encoder_decoder.htm).

Comment: Ничего не получилось с кодировкой. Решила вводить английскими буквами

Comment: И это `bravo.`